# Get-MailBoxFolderPermission

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I am trying to get MailBoxFolderpermission from diffrent users. I have diffrent tenants where i need to connect and get those. But problems is that i have some folder names in english and other in my own language so i need to make loop or comparison operator which is checking bot languages. Because i dont know which tenants are using my language and which are in english.

This is working:

`Get-MailBoxFolderPermission -Identity $userAsked":\FolderName" | select FolderName, User, AccessRights`

Those are not working:
1.

`$permCalendar = Get-MailBoxFolderPermission -Identity $userAsked | where-object {$_.FolderName -eq ":\FolderName" -or ":\Calendar"} | select FolderName, User, AccessRights`

Not working:
2.

```
 if($_.FolderType -eq ":\FolderName") {
                            Get-MailBoxFolderPermission -Identity $userAsked":\FolderName" | select FolderName, User, AccessRights
                        } elseif ($_.FolderType -eq ":\Calendar") { 
                            Get-MailBoxFolderPermission -Identity $userAsked":\Calendar" | select FolderName, User, AccessRights
                        } else {
                            Write-Host ""
                        }
```

Comment: Does `Where-Object {$_.FolderName -match 'FolderName|Calendar'}` work for you?

Comment: Nope, its only returning empty row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft made it hard by localizing foldernames like that.
However, it can be done if you first query for the localized Name or the FolderID of what is called `Calendar` in English and use that instead:

```
$calendar = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $userAsked -FolderScope Calendar | 
            Where-Object { $_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'} | Select-Object Name, FolderId
```

Now you can do the rest of your script using either the `$calendar.Name` or the `$calendar.FolderId`

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $userAsked":\$($calendar.FolderId)"
```